# MANY_MANY Yii query limiting to list of related records

Tags: php, sql, yii, many-to-many

I have a Yii app that contains Products and Interests with a MANY_MANY relationship. These are mapped, obviously, with the following relation:

```
            'interests'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Interest', 'interest_product_assignment(product_id,interest_id)'),
```

I wish to query Products using CDbCriteria like so:

```
$products = Product::model()->with('interests')->findAll($criteria);
```

This query is working fine. I need to extend it to limit it to only certain interests that I have the ids of stored in an array. I believe this should be possible with something like:

```
    $products = Product::model()->with(
        'interests',
        array('condition' => {not_sure_what_to_put_here})
    )->findAll($criteria);
```

I'm not sure how to finish the above query and have been looking for a while. It's not that I can't find anything on this, but I can't understand anything I've dug up.

Can anyone spot how to complete this query?

**EDIT**

What I've tried upon Telvin's suggestion:

```
    $products = Product::model()->with(
        'interests',
        array('condition' => "interests_interests.interest_id IN ($selectedInterestsString)")
    )->findAll($criteria);
```

Not adding an 'IN' statement to query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array of provided ids:

```
$array_ids =    array('1','24','350','4609', ....)    
$array_ids_str = '"' . implode('","', array_values($array_ids)) . '"';

$products = Product::model()->with(array(
        'interests'=> array('condition' => "interest_id_column IN ($array_ids_str)"
    )))->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Telvin. It's not quite working for me. I'm not sure if I've written the correct thing, but no IN statement is added to the SQL that results. I'll post what I've written.

Comment: In your EDIT part, I see that your query is incorrect, after my "with" was array.

Comment: I see. Will check this out soon, thanks for coming back to me.